# JavaScript: Regex to replace this "2018Jun12-2018Jul11" date string with this "Jun 12, 2018 - Jul 11, 2018" date string

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have the following string:

```
var str = "2018Jun12-2018Jul11";
```

Is there a regular expression that I could use to convert it to: `"Jun 12, 2018 - Jul 11, 2018"` with `str.replace()`?

Comment: use split string instead and just reconstruct the string

Comment: If order or format of date is fixed in `"2018Jun12-2018Jul11"`, then just use javascript string manipulation. Why regex ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this involves a bit of string formatting logic via a "replacer" callback, one solution that is based on [`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) would be:

```js
const input = `2018Jun12-2018Jul11`;
const output = input.replace(
  /* Search for matches of this pattern, and extract groups */
  /(\d+)([a-z]+)(\d+)/gi, 
  /* Replacer function formats the extracted values as required */
  (_,year,month,date) => `${month} ${date}, ${year}`
)
/* If you need white space around the hyphen */
.split('-').join(' - ')

console.log(input, ' -> ', output)
```

The idea here is to match any occurance of pattern "year number `(\d+)`,month string `[a-z]+`, date number `(\d+)`" in your input string. The use of `( )` in the pattern causes corresponding values to be extracted from the pattern match. The `replacer` callback returns a string that rearranges those extracted values to the desired format. This string becomes the replacement value for the match in the output.

Hope that helps

Comment: It's really close, but for some reason the output string attaches the first digit of the date to the month name and the second digit is on it's own. The output I get is: `2018Jun12-2018Jul11  ->  Jun1 2, 2018-Jul1 1, 2018`

Comment: @Legion that's because `\w` matches `0-9` as well so the `\w+` is absorbing the first digit in the day. You need `/(\d+)([a-z]+)(\d+)/gi` instead

Comment: That should be `[a-zA-Z]`, no?

Comment: @Seb `i` flag makes it case-insensitive

Comment: @Legion my appologies, I was tinkering with the regex and saved an error - just restored my prior answer :-)